Eclipse not displaying project as expected?
I am in the "Project explorer" and it is not showing each top-level package as a collapsible node.. instead it lists each possible sub-package on the main bar
How do I get it to display the packages as folders?
I had this working in the "Project explorer" before & I'm unsure what configuration is missing

Make sure that in the view menu (the three dots) Package Presentation > Flat is selected. If this is not the issue, please show a screenshot.
